# 403 error with angular.js post and django rest framework

Tags: angularjs, django, rest, django-rest-framework, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to make a really simple login form using angular.js on front and api rest on the back end. Here is the form on html side :

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="login-username" class="control-label">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="login-username" ng-model="loginData.email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="login-password" class="control-label">Password:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" id="login-password" ng-model="loginData.password" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="login()">Login as {$ loginData.email $}</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here is my angular controller (NB: I know there is no issue here because I have a very similar one for a register function that works just fine):

```
mainApp.controller("mainCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.loginData = {"email":"bernard@mail.com","password":"pass"};
    $scope.login = function() {
        return $http.post('/api/v1/auth/login/', 
            $scope.loginData
        ).success(function(data, status){
            alert("success : "+status);
            console.log(data);
        }).error(function(data, status){
            alert("error : "+status);
        });
    }
});
```

And here is my angular app, which includes the csrf headers :

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []).config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{$');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('$}');
}).run(run);


function run($http) {
    $http.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
    $http.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
}
```

On the django side, I have a login view that works perfectly for the get and not for the post method. And that's where I'm lost.

```
class LoginView(views.APIView):
    """
    View for login user
    """
    queryset = BaseUser.objects.all()

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        print("get_login098765") # THIS IS PRINTED PERFECTLY
        return Response()

    def post(self, request, format=None): #THIS THROWS 403 ERROR
        print("post_login098765") #THIS IS NOT PRINTED
        return Response()
```

What am I missing ? Thanks !

EDIT:

I'm receiving a file named login containing : `{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}`

Comment: You need to send csrf token in the headers.

Comment: Please checkout my edit. Thanks

Comment: Do you see the csrf token in the headers of the request payload? You can check in developer tools.

Comment: @ZackTanner Yes i can see it.

Comment: Not the response, the request. And there, look for the header `X-CSRFToken`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your edit, the message:
`{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}` is being thrown by Django REST Framework and pertains to your permissions on that ViewSet. I would recommend having a look at http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/

That could consist of adding default authentication classes to your settings file, like so:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    )
}
```

Or view based, like so:

```
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

class LoginView(api.APIView):
  authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)
  permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
  [...]
```

UPDATE: Since using `AllowAny` as the permissions worked, you can do the following to restrict those permissions to the post route. Here's an example:

```
class LoginView(api.APIView):
  queryset = BaseUser.objects.all()

  def get_permissions(self):
      if self.request.method == 'POST':
          return (permissions.AllowAny(),)

      return (permissions.IsAuthenticated(),)
```

This will override the permissions for POST requests on this endpoint, and default to IsAuthenticated for other routes.

Comment: Thanks @ZackTanner. I'm sure the problems is around those issues. But unfortunately, what you provided is not solving the problem yet.

Comment: Try setting the permission_classes to `AllowAny`. First import that permission, `from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny`, then update permission_classes to be `permission_classes = (AllowAny,)`

Comment: it worked ! Thank you very much ! But is it not dangerous to have AllowAny, and why is it not working for IsAuthenticated ? Thanks !

Comment: Probably because the user is not authenticated, thus they are being denied access. This specific view seems to be used to authenticate the user, so IsAuthenticated will always be false until that user is authenticated. Take a look at this post: http://richardtier.com/2014/03/06/110/ -- I actually used this as a reference when creating a auth viewset.

Comment: No problem. I updated my post with a potentially more safe solution, feel free to check it out.

Answer (score 2):

From what I read, the CRSF parameters need to be applied in the config function:

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []).config(function($interpolateProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{$');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('$}');
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
}).run(run);
```

Comment: and that the configuration is attached to `$httpProvider` and not `$http`

Comment: This is not helping and the {$ are not interpreted anymore.